# Detect if NSNumber is zero, nil or 0

Tags: objective-c, null

I have a variable in core data.  I want to detect for the cases where it is nil zero, null or otherwise does not have a nice value such as 222 or 333.

This should be trivial but I am getting caught up in Objective-C's syntax.

Following code is *not* working:

```
if (_item.id!=nil && _item.id!=0) {
//do something
}
```

Of note id should be an NSNumber.

It is defined as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
```

I should clarify that it is not working when the value logs to console as 0.

Given the way variable types and core data work, I cannot tell you what causes the variable to log to console as '0' but something is causing it to do so.  Basically, I want to exclude cases where the value is anything other than a non-zero integer (in mathematical, not computer science terms).

Comment: The two conditions in `_item.id!=nil && _item.id!=0` are identical, semantically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To check the numeric value stored in an `NSNumber`, you have to call one of the methods which give you a primitive type.

e.g. `integerValue`, `unsignedLongLongValue`, `doubleValue`

To correctly check for `nil` and a value of `0`, you need the following:

```
if (_item.id != nil && [_item.id intValue] != 0) {
    // code here
}
```

Because sending a message to a `nil` reference returns `0`, you can take a shortcut:

```
if ([_item.id intValue] != 0) ...
```

This works because `_item.id` has to be non-nil to return a non-zero value from `intValue`.

Comment: Would this also detect if it is totally empty?

Comment: What does totally empty mean?

Comment: @user1904273 An instance of `NSNumber` always has a value -- there is no "totally empty."

Answer (score 2):

As this `NSManagedObject` is of type `NSNumber`, simply check the intValue.

```
  if (!_item.id.intValue){
       //Method will stop in here if the id is nil/0 etc.
  }
```

However, it is not recommended to name a variable **`id`**, I suggest you rename it to **`itemId`**

In the same way you shouldn't name something '`string`', or '`new`' etc as these conflict with Apple's own native naming policies

Comment: An id field is unlikely to be a bool.

Comment: Checking boolValue means checking if the number equal 0/nil or not, so this does work and the cleanest way to check. 0 or nil means NO and any other number means YES, therefore checking boolValue is ideal here

Comment: It works, but it completely disguises the actual intent, which is far more important than any other consideration.

Comment: Using `intValue` has the benefit of allowing the same idiom of `(![_item.id intValue])`, but without the downside as disguising the type of the field.  It's also a single character shorter, for those who care about such things.

Comment: Good point about `id`, but you should explain the *reason* that it's not a good idea, which is that `id` is a keyword and built-in type in Objective-C, so using `id` as a name can easily lead to bugs that are hard to spot.

Answer (score 0):

To check the numeric value stored in an NSNumber, you have to call one of the methods which give you a primitive type.

e.g. integerValue, unsignedLongLongValue, doubleValue

To correctly check for nil and a value of 0, you need the following:

```
if (_item.id != nil && [_item.id intValue] != 0) {
    // code here
}
```

Because sending a message to a nil reference returns 0, you can take a shortcut:

```
if ([_item.id intValue] != 0)
```